# Hiding the protocol behind API?

Tags: api-design, erlang

I go on challenging the Erlang-promoted practices. I see that [they advise to hide the messaging behind API](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/more-on-multiprocessing#secret-messages)

> We love messages, but we keep them secret: 
>   Something annoying with the previous example

```
5> Pid ! {self(), {store, bacon}}.
{<0.33.0>,{store,bacon}}
6> Pid ! {self(), {take, bacon}}.
{<0.33.0>,{take,bacon}}
7> Pid ! {self(), {take, turkey}}.
{<0.33.0>,{take,turkey}}
8> flush().
Shell got {<0.51.0>,ok}
Shell got {<0.51.0>,{ok,bacon}}
Shell got {<0.51.0>,not_found}
```

> is that the programmer who's going to use the fridge has to know about the protocol that's been invented for that process. That's a useless burden. A good way to solve this is to abstract messages away with the help of functions dealing with receiving and sending them:

```
12> kitchen:store(Pid, water).
ok
13> kitchen:take(Pid, water).
{ok,water}
14> kitchen:take(Pid, juice).
not_found
```

Do my eyes mislead me or it is really easier to learn functional API than "the protocol"? What if we wrap the API into another API to hide the protocol once more. Will it make situation similarly better?

Comment: This just looks like converting the "verb" from "data" into "function". If you need to perform additional validations that must be hard-coded for each function (verb), such as having separate validation logic for `store` and `take`, then you may have a legitimate reason to perform such validation on both sides - on the caller's side as well as on the recipient's side.

Answer (score 5):

As an example is the X windowing protocol; it's a binary socket api that everyone tells you to use the XCB library to wrap its use. This means that the programmer using doesn't need to worry about correctly parsing and composing the packets.

On top of that people tell you to not use XCB directly but instead use a widget toolkit to abstract XCB away. This toolkit is often object oriented and each widget then encapsulates all the information it needs which includes the widget hierarchy subscribing to the user input at the correct times,...

Then there are people who write libraries to wrap the toolkit into something they find simpler to use.

That's usually where it stops though.

As another example no-one does raw http instead they tell you to use curl which will handle parsing, dealing with the different content types, cookies, if you add an encryption library it will also do https, ...

So yes it's common to wrap a non-trivial protocol in a api that hides all the complexities.